# How competitive are faculty jobs in the UK, as compared with the U.S.?

Tags: career-path, job, faculty-application, united-kingdom

I wonder when a faculty position at a top UK university is advertised, how many applications will be submitted. I am just asking about an estimate of the average. For example, consider a Reader position in an engineering field.

I wish to know how competitive are the faculty jobs in the UK in comparison with the US.

Comment: Depends on uni, department and location.

Comment: _in comparison with the US_ — Your baseline for comparison _also_ depends on university, department, and location.  You really need to be more specific.